# Upload multiple header files at once - CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have a folder that has folders inside that has multiple .h files. Is there anyway I can add all those at once to my project?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? You want that CodeBlocks will see the folder and you're going to include all headers without giving the path?

Comment: @OnurTuna I meant like drag my header files into CodeBlocks instead of having to create a new file Everytime. I did try simple dragging but the files won't show up in Code Blocks.